# How to get RestAPI data using axios in actions of Vuex?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have tried to get RestAPI data to use axios in actions of Vuex system
and display that information in components.
So I tried to make small app using test API sample,
but error occuered.

I used that [test API](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments).
Its include 5 keys, like "postId","id","name","email","body".
In my case, I just want to display "id" information to my component.
but error message saied "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"

and my Vuex code is below
store/customer.ts

```
    import { MutationTree, ActionTree, GetterTree } from "vuex";
import { RootState } from "../types";
import { Customer } from "../types/customer";
import axios from "axios";

interface State {
  customer: Customer;
}
export const state = () => ({
  customer: []
});
export const getters: GetterTree<State, RootState> = {
  customer: (state: State) => state.customer
};
export const mutations: MutationTree<State> = {
  setCustomer(state: State, customer: Customer) {
    state.customer = customer;
  }
};
export const actions: ActionTree<State, RootState> = {
  getCustomerInfo: async ({ commit }) => {
    const data = await axios.get(
      "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments"
    );
    commit("setCustomer", data.data.customer);
  }
};
export default {state,getters,mutations,actions}
```

I defined type of RootState and Customer in types direcoty.
I really don't understand how to set the data to setCustomer in mutations
through acitons.
types/index.ts

```
export interface RootState {}
```

types/customer.ts

```
    export interface Customer {
    postId?: number;
    id?: number;
    name?: string;
    email?: string;
    body?: string;
  }
```

and my vue component below
test.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Counter />
    <p>vuex test</p>
    <p>{{ customer.id }}</p>
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, namespace, Vue } from 'nuxt-property-decorator'
import { Customer } from '~/types/customer'
const SCustomer = namespace('customer')

@Component({})
export default class extends Vue {
  @SCustomer.Action getCustomerInfo!: Function
  @SCustomer.State customer!: Customer

  async created() {
    await this.getCustomerInfo()
  }
}
</script>
```

I really understand vuex!
Could someone advise me,please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the state, make sure the request is success and you have data before committing to the mutations. You need a getter in order to access the state data. Make sure you can access to the state Actions, otherwise, you'll need to mapActions. Hopefully, this help.

```
import { MutationTree, ActionTree, GetterTree } from "vuex";
import { RootState } from "../types";
import { Customer } from "../types/customer";
import axios from "axios";

interface State {
  customer: Customer;
}
export const state = () => ({
  customer: []
});
export const getters: GetterTree<State, RootState> = {
  customer: (state: State) => state.customer
};
export const mutations: MutationTree<State> = {
  setCustomer(state: State, customer: Customer) {
    state.customer = customer;
  }
};
export const actions: ActionTree<State, RootState> = {
  getCustomerInfo: async ({ commit }) => {
    const data = await axios.get(
      "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments"
    ).then((response) => {
        if(response.status === 'success'){
            commit("setCustomer", data.data.customer);
        }
   })
  };
};
export default {state, getters, mutations, actions}
```

In the Vue instance

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Counter />
    <p>vuex test</p>
    <p>{{ customer.id }}</p>
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, namespace, Vue } from 'nuxt-property-decorator'
import { Customer } from '~/types/customer'
const SCustomer = namespace('customer')

@Component({})
export default class extends Vue {
  @SCustomer.Action getCustomerInfo!: Function
  @SCustomer.State customer!: Customer

    computed: {
       ...mapGetters(['customer'])
    },

    created() {
        this.getCustomerInfo()
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much your advise! 
And I tried to rewrite my code from your advise. 
But some error occurred.
In store/customer.ts at "response.status === 'success'",
error message is below.
This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'number' and 'string' have no overlap.

Comment: and in test.vue, I think computed methods replace get method in nuxt-property-decorator. So I rewrite like that
"get() {
       mapGetters(['customer'])
    };"

Comment: and in store/customer.ts at "data.data.customer",
error message is below.
Property 'data' does not exist on type 'void'.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. I'm sorry I'm super beginner, I tried to understand your answer........

Comment: @drunkdolphin, I think your response status would be 200 (ok) so make sure you console the response data out. change it response.status === 200

Comment: you don't have to change the computed. Just print out the customer using {{customer}} to make sure the getters is working. If you receive empty array, just add methods: {...mapActions(['getCustomerInfo'])} underneath the created

Comment: Than you so much! I understood and fix my issues. I really appreciate it! Thanks !

Comment: @drunkdolphin, I'm glade you solved your issue. If you mind to share the community how you solved the issue so that everyone can follow next time with the similar issue.

Comment: Mr.Kimsea Sok, Thank you so much for your advise!
I post my answer!

Answer (score 0):

In the test.vue file,
I changed from {{customer.id}} to {{customer}} in template.

In store/customer.ts,
I changed actions function like that.

commit('setCustomer',data.data.response) ⇒　commit('setCustomer',data.data)

In first code, I got data from test API, but my request data code was wrong.
Mr.Kimsea Sok, Thank you so much for your advise!!